# How to customize reset password Token in Asp.net core Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I use `Asp.netCore identity` in my project, i added this package:

`"IdentityServer4.AspNetIdentity": "1.0.0",`

to my project, i use this method for generation `reset password token`:

```
 string code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

it works fine, but the generated code is something like this:

```
/DgEiBeBT3zArfkZzxY8/hxCebWeT3cV/c xXdQDV2w9AOey7iW5KwsJYtuaV qe87KSXRnmYXNNrw2NY2DQNWsMgy3vxBIZgkgnUGk6ekxItf5XUmxRl5g6bFHZ2XHRBqmpcbj1yGDpoYkUkYvXUhtaDvszgmVOn8GjmFsyrPwFY5ARsd4LYygclKWFCG2TsAEkixVIwqmliBeITrzCGm4HoM i1nm15ZRb/bA
```

> Is there a way to customize this method to return six digit number
>   instead of  above string?

Comment: 6 digit number is too easy to crack by brute-force. And not too hard to discover the vulnerability either - an attacker would have to reset the password himself once to see the pattern.

Comment: @trailmax thank u for posting ur idea, i want to customize this token may be on another pattern, i mean for example 6 digit, i just want a way for customizing this code, i googled but i didn't find good article about it, do u know a way for doing this customization?

Comment: No, there is no easy way to "customise" the way token looks - it contains some data and is encrypted. You can't easily "customise" the way encrypted data looks.

Comment: @pejman did you find any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to customise the generated code you have to create your own, custom token provider (what you see below is the minimum you have to paste before writing your own code):

```
public class CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider<TUser> : IUserTwoFactorTokenProvider<TUser> where TUser : User
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _db;
    public DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions Options { get; }
    public IDataProtector Protector { get; }
    public string Name => Options.Name;

    public CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider(
        IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider, 
        IOptions<CustomPasswordResetTokenProviderOptions> options,
        YourDbContext db)
    {
        if (dataProtectionProvider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataProtectionProvider));
        Options = options?.Value ?? new DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions();
        Protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(Name ?? "DataProtectorTokenProvider"); 

        _db = db;
    }

    public async Task<string> GenerateAsync(string purpose, UserManager<TUser> userManager, TUser user)
    {
        // create and store your custom (i.e.: 6 digit) code in the database
    }

    public async Task<bool> ValidateAsync(string purpose, string encodedToken, UserManager<TUser> userManager, TUser user)
    {
        // check if the code in the database is correct
    }
} 

public class CustomPasswordResetTokenProviderOptions : DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions { }
```

After that you have to supply your token provider in `AddIdentity()` function in your `ConfigureServices()` method:

```
services.AddIdentity<YourUser, ...>(o =>
    {
        ...
        o.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = typeof(CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider<User>).Name.Split("`")[0];
    })
    .AddRoles<...>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<YourDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddTokenProvider<CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider<User>>("CustomPasswordResetTokenProvider");
```

Also, apparently the preferred way of using these tokens by microsoft these days is not storing them in a db at all but rather generating them in a deterministic manner, so they can be regenerated and checked during validation without wasting additional space.